# VueJs Enter-transition animation not working on click

Tags: css, vue.js

The code is supposed to take a user's entry in the input box, push it to the end of the "tasks" array when "ADD TASK" is clicked which is then displayed using v-for. However, the list-enter-active animation doesn't work. It just snaps into the browser's display instead of easing in. "REMOVE TASK" works like it should though.

```
<template>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>To-Do It</h1>
      <transition-group name="list" tag="p">
        <div
          v-for="(item, index) in tasks"
          v-bind:item="item"
          v-bind:index="index"
          v-bind:key="item.id"
        >
          {{ item.count }}
        </div>
      </transition-group>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a task" v-model="userinput" />
      <div>
        <p v-bind:class="{ buttondiv: pshow }" v-on:click="addtask">
          ADD TASK
        </p>
        <p v-bind:class="{ buttondiv: pshow }" v-on:click="removetask">
          REMOVE TASK
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Todo",
  data: function() {
    return {
      userinput: "",
      tasks: [],
      show: true,
      pshow: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addtask: function() {
      if (this.userinput != "") {
        this.tasks.push({ count: this.userinput });
        this.userinput = "";
        console.log(this.tasks);
      } else {
        return "failed";
      }
    },
    removetask: function() {
      this.tasks.pop(this.userinput);
    }
  }

};
</script>

<style>
@import "../assets/Todo.css";

.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
</style>
```

Comment: where does `transtion-group` come from?

Comment: It's an inbuilt VueJs CSS class used for transition animation.

Comment: what happens, when you set init values for `opacity` and `transform` withe classes `.list-enter-to, .list-leave`?